# Two opencart installations on same domain?

Tags: directory, installation, opencart

I have a bilingual/bizonal Opencart store.
For geotargeting purpose I need to add a new store in a new directory (I do not want a subddomain).
I would like to clone all the store and database in the new directory and then make the necessary changes there.
Is it possible? May be a new oc installation?
How?

Many thanks
Ugo

Answer (score 1):

OpenCart already supports

```
Multi channel
Multi domain
Multi store
Multi currency
Multi langauge
```

Therefore your language and currency set, or multi store can be limited to that particular language.. including having a store default to a certain theme, a certain currency and language.

It is not a good idea to have hundreds of different opencart folders, just create a new store and add the country and language and currency set across. You don't need subdomains either.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply,
Actually I need to setup two different geographic targets in Google Webmaster Tools. In order to do so, I need to have each language/zone in a different directory.
Ugo